# dynamic sql getting record in every id

Tags: sql-server-2008, dynamic-sql

say i have this record

```
    id     debit      credit     balance
   001     100         0          100 
   001     200         0          300
   001      0          100        200
   002     50          0          50
   002     100         0          150
   002     0           200        -50
   003     50          0          50
   003     500         0          550
   003     0           100        450
```

now what i want to happen is i want to get every 2 records of every id in the record that it will look like the following:

```
    id     debit      credit     balance
   001     100         0          100 
   001     200         0          300
   002     50          0          50
   002     100         0          150
   003     50          0          50
   003     500         0          550
```

is it possible to have this output using dynamic sql? if it can, can anybody help me, I am stuck here. Thank you.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE debit <> 0` ??

Comment: no that is not what i want to happen.. i need to get the top 2 record of each id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
;WITH Data
AS
(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id) MyRowNumber
  FROM mytable 
)
SELECT * 
FROM Data
WHERE MyRowNumber IN (1,2)
```

Change `ORDER BY` clause to get the order you want.